# Uploading file to S3 in Flutter Web (with link from backend)

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 picked with the filepicker package in flutter web. The backend provides me the link to upload the file, so in theory all I need to do is a PUT request to said link. The problem I'm having is (I think) properly sending the file in the body of the request, because if I upload the file directly to S3 with postman on the provided link, it works.

The code below is what I've been working on, after several iterations. I've tried forming the file with http.MultipartFile.fromBytes but the result is the same. I've also tried to send the request with a normal http.put request, and the error there is when I put a Multipart File in the body, if I try to json.encode, I get an error that it wasn't successful, if I don't encode it, it also gives a type error.

This current code is giving and XMLHttpRequest error, which from what I understand is probably due to a CORS error, the thing is I don't understand how that could be. Any input is appreciated!

Here is the code for uploading the image to the link provided by the backend:

```
Map<String, String> customHeaders2 = {
          "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key":
              "",
          "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm": "AES256",
          "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5":
              "",
          "Content-Type": "image/png",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept": "*/*",
        };
 
 
        final request = http.MultipartRequest(
          'PUT',
          //body of the response from request to the backend for the link
          Uri.parse(jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["data"]),
        );
 
        request.headers.addAll(customHeaders2);
 
        request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile(
            'file',
            http.ByteStream.fromBytes(file.bytes!),
            file.bytes!.length,
            filename: file.name,
            //contentType: MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
          ),
        );
 
        await request.send().then((value) => print(value.statusCode));
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the browser / developer tools / network tab... what error does it show? Do you see a failed CORS pre-flight? Try the above code in a pure Dart project - does it work there (which would point to a CORS problem). "how that could be" - it seems possible the server isn't adding the required CORS headers.

Comment: Also, read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Yes, I checked the developer tools, and the error is this: has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm not sure what I should do to fix it.

Comment: Check 1, 2a, 2b and 2c of the document above. You should be able to see the request in developer tools.